# How to pivot a table to a view on matching-length delimited cells

Tags: t-sql, split, pivot, delimiter

Disclaimer: I'm dealing with a rather old legacy system so any comments telling me about poor design are redundant, although I do genuinely appreciate any such sentiment. There is a new version that solves most legacy problems but we still have to maintain the old system, so basically, we have to manage for now.

---

I have a table that looks like this (yes, that is a single column, I know):

[image: Currency table]

And I need a view (for reporting purposes) that will dynamically process the data in said table and return this:

[image: Desired view]

The values are \n-delimited (shudder) and you can assume there will always be the same number of values in each cell (9 in the example, although other databases could have 4 or 12 or any number), although I suppose having NULL-insertion in the event of missing values couldn't hurt. They will also always be in a matching order (as in the example, 'AUD', 'Australian Dollar', and '$' are all the first values in their respective cells, and so on).

I've found various approaches to splitting a single cell out into a view, but nothing that covers merging data in such a way as I require. Sitting at home with a cold has not helped my research capabilities. Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope!

Bonus points for tidy, relatively readable SQL examples, although I'm anticipating messiness as a natural by-product of the hackish nature of my required solution.

Comment: Plus one simply for pre-emptively asking people not to waste space waxing poetic about design issues.  Sometimes we don't get to pick the designs we're forced to work with.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.  I didn't take the time to build out the tables, but it should be fairly obvious where you can replace my variables with your rows.  You will also want to do a replace char(10) where I have used commas.  You could package it up in a table valued function and then call as a view.

```
declare @xml1 xml 
declare @xml2 xml
declare @xml3 xml
declare @c1 nvarchar(250)
declare @c2 nvarchar(250)
declare @c3 nvarchar(250)

set @c1 = N'AUD,CAD,EUR,GBP,JPY,NZD,USD,KES,CHF';
set @c2 = N'Australian Dollar,Canadian Dollar,Euro,Pound Sterling,Yen,New Zealand Dollar,United States Dollar,Kenyan Shilling, Swiss Franc';
set @c3 = N'$,$,C,L,Y,$,$,K,F';

-- you'd use replace(@c1, char(10), '</r><r>') etc etc for /n delimited code
set @xml1 = N'<root><r>' + replace(@c1,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>';
set @xml2 = N'<root><r>' + replace(@c2,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>';
set @xml3 = N'<root><r>' + replace(@c3,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>';

select code.code, name.name, symbol.symbol
from 
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @@rowcount) as ck, 
   c.value('.','varchar(max)') as [code]
   from @xml1.nodes('//root/r') as a(c)) as code
inner join
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @@rowcount) as nk, 
   n.value('.','varchar(max)') as [name]
   from @xml2.nodes('//root/r') as a(n)) as name on code.ck = name.nk
inner join
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @@rowcount) as sk, 
   s.value('.','varchar(max)') as [symbol]
   from @xml3.nodes('//root/r') as a(s)) as symbol on symbol.sk = name.nk
```

You can run this as a single script in SSMS for verification that it works.  No schema necessary.

Comment: Excellent answer. Relatively simple and seemingly performant. With a few changes it plugged into my solution without any issues. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jeff Moden's Tally Ho! CSV splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
WITH 
E1(N) AS (
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
       SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
       SELECT 1 UNION ALL
       SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
       SELECT s.N1,
              ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
       FROM cteStart s
)
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
       Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
;
```

and inline CTE data like this

```
with 
data as (select Num,Currencies from (values
        (1,'AUD'+char(10)+'CAD'+char(10)+'USD'+char(10)+'KES')
       ,(2,'Australian DOllar'+char(10)+'Canadian Dollar'+char(10)+'US Dollar'+char(10)+'Kenyan Shilling')
       ,(3,'$'+char(10)+'$'+char(10)+'$'+char(10)+'k')
    )data(Num,Currencies)
),
```

The solution is as simple as this:

```
map as (select * from (values
          (1,'Code')
         ,(2,'Name')
         ,(3,'Symbol')
    )map(Num,Col )
)
select
     ItemNumber
    ,max(Code) as Code
    ,max(Name) as Name
    ,max(Symbol) as Symbol
from (
    select 
         map.Num
        ,map.Col 
        ,c.Item
        ,c.ItemNumber
    from data
    join map
       on map.Num   = data.Num
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(data.Currencies,char(10)) c
) t
pivot (max(Item) for Col in (Code,Name,Symbol)) pvt
group by ItemNumber
```

to give us:

```
ItemNumber     Code Name                 Symbol
-------------- ---- -------------------- ---------------
1              AUD  Australian DOllar    $
2              CAD  Canadian Dollar      $
3              USD  US Dollar            $
4              KES  Kenyan Shilling      k
```

Comment: Note that `char(10)` (or CTRL-J) is the line-feed ASCII character represented by `\n` in C-like languages that OP's predecessor is using as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Helps. Run all together or replace the table variable with a temptable.

**Sample Data:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#table') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #table
    END
DECLARE #table TABLE(ATTRIBUTELVAUE VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #table
SELECT
'AFN
ALL
DZD
USD
EUR
AOA
XCD
XCD
ARS'

INSERT INTO #table
SELECT
'Afghanistan
Albania
Algeria
American Samoa
Andorra
Angola
Anguilla
Antigua and Barbuda
Argentina'

INSERT INTO #table
SELECT
'AF
AL
DZ
AS
AD
AO
AI
AG
AR'
```

**Query:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END

DECLARE @StartLoop INT
DECLARE @EndLoop INT
DECLARE @Code TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                 Code VARCHAR(250))
DECLARE @Name TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                 Name VARCHAR(250))
DECLARE @Symbol TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
                   Symbol VARCHAR(250))

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ID,
      *
INTO #Temp
FROM #table

SELECT @StartLoop = MIN(ID),
      @EndLoop = MAX(ID)
FROM #Temp

WHILE @StartLoop <= @EndLoop
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @WorkingString VARCHAR(MAX)

       SELECT @WorkingString = ATTRIBUTELVAUE + CHAR(10) + ' '
       FROM #Temp
       WHERE ID = @StartLoop
       --print @WorkingString

       WHILE CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @WorkingString) > 0
          BEGIN
             DECLARE @SearchCharacter INT
             DECLARE @WorkingStringLength INT
             DECLARE @TempStringLength INT
             DECLARE @TempString VARCHAR(MAX)

             SET @WorkingStringLength = LEN(@WorkingString)
             SET @SearchCharacter = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @WorkingString)
             SET @TempString = SUBSTRING(@WorkingString, 1, @SearchCharacter - 1)

             SET @TempStringLength = LEN(@TempString)

             SET @WorkingString = SUBSTRING(@WorkingString, @SearchCharacter + 1, @WorkingStringLength)

             SET @TempString = REPLACE(@TempString, CHAR(13), '')

             IF @StartLoop = 1
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @Code
                    SELECT @TempString
                END
             IF @StartLoop = 2
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @Name
                    SELECT @TempString
                END
             IF @StartLoop = 3
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO @Symbol
                    SELECT @TempString
                END

          END

       SET @StartLoop = @StartLoop + 1
    END

SELECT Code,
      Name,
      Symbol
FROM @Code AS c
    JOIN @Name AS n
    ON c.ID = n.ID
    JOIN @Symbol AS s
    ON s.ID = n.ID
```

**Cleanup:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TEMP') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #TEMP
    END
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#table') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE #table
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I needed a view, this ended up being my solution:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CurrencyTableGenerator]()
RETURNS
    @CurrencyTable TABLE(
        Code    NVARCHAR(250)
        ,Name   NVARCHAR(250)
        ,Symbol NVARCHAR(250)
    )
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @xml1 XML
DECLARE @xml2 XML
DECLARE @xml3 XML
DECLARE @C1 NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @C2 NVARCHAR(250)
DECLARE @c3 NVARCHAR(250)
SET @c1 = (SELECT ...)
SET @c2 = (SELECT ...)
SET @c3 = (SELECT ...)
SET @xml1 = N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(@c1, CHAR(10), '</r><r>') + '</r></root>';
SET @xml2 = N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(@c2, CHAR(10), '</r><r>') + '</r></root>';
SET @xml3 = N'<root><r>' + REPLACE(@c3, CHAR(10), '</r><r>') + '</r></root>';

INSERT INTO @CurrencyTable
SELECT Code.Code, Name.Name, Symbol.Symbol
FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT) AS ck, 
   c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS [Code]
   FROM @xml1.nodes('//root/r') AS a(c)) AS Code
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT) AS nk, 
   n.value('.', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS [Name]
   FROM @xml2.nodes('//root/r') AS a(n)) AS Name ON Code.ck = Name.nk
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT) AS sk, 
   s.value('.', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS [Symbol]
   FROM @xml3.nodes('//root/r') AS a(s)) AS Symbol ON Symbol.sk = Name.nk

RETURN
END

GO

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CurrencyView]
AS
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[CurrencyTableGenerator]()

GO
```

Thanks to RThomas for the function.